# WCF calling the WSDL creates a large memory consumption for the w3wp process

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7, w3wp

We have deployed a very large WCF service with lots of contracts and functionality.

The service runs from an independent server with a unique app pool on IIS 7.

The service is configured as a per call service, and no static instances are initialized, there are no unmanaged objects in the service at all.

Lately we have noticed that the service consumes almost all of the server free RAM.

From tests that we have done the main memory usage is when the service is first called, not even by invoking any method but only calling its WSDL.

This memory is not getting released as long as the application runs.

We believe this is causing performance issues that makes our service unresponsive.

How can I farther test the issue ? what else should I check or isolate to get to the bottom of this ?

Comment: We can't help without any code... but Why are you sure this memory is not getting released? Maybe it is taken after that by another piece of code. Try to take small pieces from your application and run them in separate and see what caused the problem. Also make sure you're disposing all things you have to dispose and don't register to static events (but there are more things to check).

Comment: I am sure it is not from any code since I have not invoked any method on the server, I just called is WSDL to get a reference to it and noticed the memory usage of the machine. also I have no static instances on it, and there are no unmanaged objects to dispose...

Comment: Which process(es) did you profile to determine that it is indeed your web service consuming free memory?

Comment: on the running processes list you can see the app pool as a separate process of the w3wp, The user name column is the app pool name, the only running app on this pool is my service and so I know.